# How to encode url?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, encoding

I have a textView1 and when I type something and press a button URL opens. When I type in English everything works fine, but I also have to type in russian and it doesn't work. So I need to encode it. Can someone help with coding?

my SozdikViewerController.h file

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SozdikViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button_Ask;
-(IBAction)ask;
@end
```

my SozdikViewerController.m file

```
#import "SozdikViewController.h"
-(IBAction)ask{


 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@&app_request=true", [[self textView1] text]];

  NSString *newString;
newString = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newString]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

newString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Thanks. Now the button opens url, but instead of for example russian word "мама", the word "РјР°РјР°". How can I edit code to solve this problem?

Comment: i am not understanding your problem...  n i think its also work for russian word also...